# layer in menu singleton not displaying

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I have made a singleton to handle menu changes (navigating through menu hierarchy) in my game. I don't know why the menu is not displaying. Please see my MenuManager classes singleton below.

MenuManager.h:

```
@interface MenuManager : NSObject
{
MenuLayerTypes currentMenuLayer;
CCLayer* runningLayer;
CCLayer* oldLayer;
}

+(MenuManager*)sharedMenuManager;
-(void)runMenuWithID:(MenuLayerTypes)menuLayerID;

@end
```

MenuManager.m:

```
#import "MenuManager.h"

@implementation MenuManager
static MenuManager* _sharedMenuManager = nil;

+(MenuManager*)sharedMenuManager
{
@synchronized([MenuManager class])
{
    if (!_sharedMenuManager)
        [[self alloc] init];
    return _sharedMenuManager;

}
return nil;
}

+(id)alloc
{
@synchronized ([MenuManager class])                   
{
    NSAssert(_sharedMenuManager == nil,
             @"Attempted to allocated a second instance of the Menu Manager singleton");
    _sharedMenuManager = [super alloc];
    return _sharedMenuManager;                     
}
return nil;
}


-(id)init
{                                                  
self = [super init];
if (self != nil)
{
     Layer = kMainMenuLayer; // default menu type
}
return self;
}

-(void)runMenuWithID:(MenuLayerTypes)menuLayerID    {
//MenuLayerTypes oldMenuLayer = currentMenuLayer;
currentMenuLayer = menuLayerID;
oldLayer.tag = 321;


switch (menuLayerID)
{
    case kMainMenuLayer:
        CCLOG(@"main menu layer");
        runningLayer = [MainMenuLayer node];
        oldLayer = runningLayer;
        break;

    case kSettingsLayer:
        runningLayer = [SettingsLayer node];
        oldLayer = runningLayer;
        break;

    case kAckLayer:
        runningLayer = [AckLayer node];
        oldLayer = runningLayer;
        break;           

    default:
        CCLOG(@"Unknown ID");
        return;
        break;
}

MainMenuScene* mainMenuScene =  (MainMenuScene *)[[CCDirector sharedDirector] runningScene];

// checks to see if a menu layer is already displayed before replacing it
if (![mainMenuScene getChildByTag:321]) {
    [mainMenuScene addChild:runningLayer];
}
else    {
    [mainMenuScene removeChildByTag:321];
    [mainMenuScene addChild:runningLayer];
}
}
@end
```

Also in the init of the MainMenuScene:

```
[[MenuManager sharedMenuManager] runMenuWithID:kMainMenuLayer];
```

How can I solve this display issue?

Comment: make sure that all your methods are called and `[MainMenuScene node]` returns non-empty layer

Comment: Make certain your sharedMenuManager is added to the scene, or some other running cocos2d node.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg: I don't really get how I'll add the sharedMenuManager to the scene. I thought the above if-else condition would take care of that and sharedMenuManager is a public class. Please could you explain further how I should add it to the scene. Thanks

Comment: I dont use scenes , have my own patterns to support the moral equivalent ... except for the first scene. I add it to that one, and it is never replaced. Maybe you could make the sharedMenuManager a scene, and 'push' it when you need it. Not certain of your game design.